# debug php script and output result and errors to a text file

Tags: php, csh

Can someone tell me how to to run a php script and output content and errors to a text file (using nohup) using csh?

Answer (score 1):

If your script has a hash-bang line (such as `#!/bin/env php`) at the top, you can run it directly like this:

```
nohup /path/to/your_script.php > /path/to/output.txt 2>&1 &
```

If not you can call the parser first with your script as an argument:

```
nohup php /path/to/your_script.php > /path/to/output.txt 2>&1 &
```

You didn't specifically mention you wanted to background the job, but usually when you nohup something you also want to background it, so I added the trailing `&` to the suggestions above.

Comment: thanks - it doesn't work though i get "ambigous output redirect"?

Comment: Can you tell us what `echo $SHELL` tells you as well as the full command you are executing?

Comment: /bin/csh    the full command is exactly as you have it

Comment: Your question states you are using bash, but that is `csh`! I don't know enough about csh to give you an equivalent. Perhaps you should edit your question with that detail. Also it's not reasonable that the full command would be just as I have it because I have dummy paths. Seeing a full copy-paste from your terminal might helps us catch other mistakes.

Comment: Perhaps you should switch to bash or zsh? If you don't have specific reasons for using csh it might be easier for you to learn standard syntax that a majority of Linux folks use.